# Knockout component updates parent model observable, but then it gets back to old value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I have a counter component and pass my parent viewmodel as `data` param to it. When user clicks, my counter component updates an observable in my parent viewmodel (its value is changing as I subscribe to it and log the new value passed).

Simplified code of parent viewmodel:

```js
const Day = class {
  constructor(params){
   this.counters = {
     hours: ko.observable(null),
     price: ko.observable(null)
   };

   this.counters.hours.subscribe(newValue => console.log(newValue)); //returns new value passed from component
}

   getHourValue(){
     console.log(this.counters.hours()); //returns null
   }
}

const day = new Day();

day.counters.hours(1); // Logs 1
day.getHourValue();    // Logs 1 as well...
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

So the value seems to update, but when I call getHourValue method, it returns null again. What's the problem here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like I got it to work by creating the class viewmodel for component inside the parent viewmodel class. Still the issue seemes a bit weird.

Comment: `this.counters.subscribe(newValue => console.log(newValue));` How is this possible when you have not defined counters as an observable?

Comment: @Ray Ops, it is a misspell, I am sorry. In my actual code it was like `this.counters.hours.subscribe`.

Comment: Is the this context registering as expected? you may need to make sure "this" is properly bound in the getHourValue method.

Comment: @contactmatt - it should not return `null` in case `this` is not properly bound should it?

Comment: I edited your question to include an interactive snippet and cannot reproduce the problem you describe. Can you show when the described behavior occurs?

Comment: @user3297291 Thank you for the edits. I think the problem was in getting wrong "this".